# How can I fix an connection timeout error when attempting to use the ipfs-http-client javascript module to upload to ipfs using a public gateway

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, ipfs

I am currently trying to learn to use ipfs in conjunction with ethereum to create web applications.  To help gain an understanding of how ipfs works, I am creating a simple React application that loads images to and from ipfs using a public gateway.  The primary javascript file for the application is here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.png';
import './App.css';

const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client');
const ipfs = ipfsClient({ host: 'ipfs.eternum.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https' }); //create an ipfs client by connecting to the infura node


class App extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
 super(props);
 this.state = 
 {
   buffer: null
 };
}

captureFile = (event) => //called when a file is submitted to the "choose file" box
{
 event.preventDefault();   //prevent the page from reloading on submit
 const file = event.target.files[0]  //get the first file submitted...
 //console.log(file);
 const reader = new window.FileReader();  //create a new file reader for the file, to convert the file to a buffer
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);   //read the file as an array buffer for ipfs
 reader.onloadend = () => {  ////once the reader is done reading the file...
   this.setState({ buffer: Buffer(reader.result) })  //set the buffer value in the state object to the array buffer
   console.log('buffer', this.state.buffer)
 }
}

onSubmit = (event) => 
{
 event.preventDefault(); //prevent the page from reloading on submit
 console.log("Submitting file to ipfs...")
 ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (error, result) => { //error and result are callback function args
   console.log('Ipfs result: ', result);
   if (error)  //if there was an error, log it and return
   {
     console.log(error);
     return
   }
 }); //<^add the file to ipfs, and then run the callback, which checks for errors and responds accordingly
}

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
       <a
         className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
         href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
         target="_blank"
         rel="noopener noreferrer"
       >
         Dapp University
       </a>
     </nav>
     <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
       <div className="row">
         <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex text-center">
           <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
             <a
               href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
               target="_blank"
               rel="noopener noreferrer"
             >
               <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
             </a>
             <p>&nbsp;</p>
             <h2>Change Meme</h2>
             <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
               <input type='file' onChange={this.captureFile} />
               <input type='submit' />
             </form>
           </div>
         </main>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}
}

export default App;
```

I have installed ipfs-http-client at version ^33.1.1.  When I attempt to use the module to upload the file to ipfs, I get the following error:

```
request.js:84          POST https://ipfs.eternum.io:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

And

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at push../node_modules/iso-stream-http/lib/request.js.ClientRequest._onFinish (request.js:84:1)
    at push../node_modules/iso-stream-http/lib/request.js.module.exports.<anonymous> (request.js:25:1)
    at push../node_modules/iso-stream-http/lib/request.js.module.exports.emit (events.js:150:1)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:624:1)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:470:1)
    at push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:167:1)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:131:1)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this issue?  I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to set up a dedicated gateway using infura, since my files were not being propagated across other nodes (since I am not paying anything for that).  As a result, I could not access the files through public gateways.  But setting up a dedicated gateway for free with infura suits my needs for now.  Now, I use the url of my dedicated gateway and my program runs without issue.

Answer (score 0):

All public gateways I have tried so far are not working, so I also had to set up a dedicated infura ipfs project, I went ahead to create a sub-domain. Note that you have to use your project id and project secret for authorization while setting up your ipfshttpclient.